# $(X_i,d_i)$ be a metric space. Show the following

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X_i,d_i)$ be metric spaces. Let $X=X_1 \times  \cdots\times X_n$.
$$S_1(x,y)=\sum\limits_1^n d_k(x_k,y_k),\quad S_2(x,y)=(\sum\limits_1^n d_k(x_k,y_k)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

i. Show that $S_1,S_2$ are distances in $X$.

ii. $(X,S_1)$ is complete if and only if $(X_i,d_i)$ are complete.

iii. $(X,S_1)$ is compact if and only if $(X_i,d_i)$ are compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part i

For $S_1$,

1- it is always positive (sum of positive terms).

If $x_1=x_2 (x_1,x_2\in X)$, then every element of $x_1$ is equal to the corresponding element in $x_2$. Therefore

$d_i(x_1^{i},x_2^{i})=d_i(x_1^{i},x_1^{i})=0$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$

Therefore

$\sum_{i} d_i(x_1^{i},x_2^{i})=0$

If $d(x_1,x_2)=0$, then $\sum_{i} d_i(x_1^{i},x_2^{i})=0$. As we have a sum of positive terms, the sum becomes $0$ if all the terms are equal to $0$. So, for all $1\leq i \leq n$

$d_i(x_1^{i},x_2^{i})=0$

According to the original metric spaces, we can deduce

$d_i(x_1^{i},x_2^{i})=0 \rightarrow x_1^{i}=x_2^{i}  \forall 1\leq i\leq n \rightarrow x_1=x_2$

2- As each of the metric spaces $(X_i,d_i)$ has the commutative property, it is not hard to see that $(X,S_1)$ is also the same.

3- For triangular inequality part, take an arbitrary element $z$ of $X$

$S_1(x,y)=\sum\limits_1^n d_k(x_k,y_k)\leq\sum\limits_1^n (d_k(x_k,z_k)+d_k(y_k,z_k))=\sum\limits_1^n d_k(x_k,z_k)+\sum\limits_1^n d_k(y_k,z_k)=S_1(x,z)+S_1(z,y)$

For $S_2(x,y)$, the first and the second conditions can be checked the same way as the previous one. The triangular inequality part can be done as below.

$S_2(x,y)=(\sum\limits_1^n d_k(x_k,y_k)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq (\sum\limits_1^n (d_k(x_k,z_k)+d_k(z_k,y_k))^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Then, using Minkowski inequality, we get

$(\sum\limits_1^n (d_k(x_k,z_k)+d_k(z_k,y_k))^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \sum\limits_1^n (d_k(x_k,z_k)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\sum\limits_1^n (d_k(z_k,y_k)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Part ii

Let's assume that $(X_i,d_i)$ are complete. Take a Cauchy sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ on $(X,S_1)$. So

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n_0(\epsilon)\in \mathbb N | S_1(x_j,x_i)<\epsilon \forall i,j>n_0(\epsilon) $

Using the formula for $S_1(x_j,x_i)$ gives

$S_1(x_j,x_i)=\sum_{k}d_k(x_{j}^{k},x_{i}^{k})<\epsilon$

Again, we have a sum of non-negative numbers. So

$d_k(x_{j}^{k},x_{i}^{k})<\epsilon \forall k$

This is the definition of a Cauchy sequence on each component $k$. As we have assumed that $(X_i,d_i)$ are complete, then each of the sequences have a limit. Take each limit and make a vector of limits. Then you just need to show that the first Cauchy sequence, $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ on $(X,S_1)$, is convergent to the vector of limits. At the end, it is not hard to see that the vector of limits is a member of $X$.

To do the other direction, Assume $(X,S_1)$ is complete. Take one of the metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and assume a Cauchy sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ on it. So

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n_0(\epsilon)\in \mathbb N | d_1(x_j,x_i)<\epsilon \forall i,j>n_0(\epsilon) $

Then, we want to make a sequence $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ on $X$, such that $y_{i}^{1}=x_{i}$, where $y_{i}^{1}$ is the first component of the $i$-th element of the sequence $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. The other components of $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ would be fixed to a member of $X_i$. It can be proved that this sequence is Cauchy and therefore, it has a limit, as we have assumed it to be complete. The first component of the limit, is the limit of the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Part iii

To show that $(X,S_1)$ is compact, you may show that for any sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, there exists a sub-sequence that is convergent. Now, if you consider a certain component $k$ of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, you get the sequence $\{x_{i}^{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, which is a sequence in the metric space $(X_k,d_k)$. As $(X_k,d_k)$ is assumed to be compact for all $k$, for every sequence in $(X_k,d_k)$, there exists a sub-sequence $\{z_{i}^{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{x_{i}^{k}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$that is convergent to some limit in $X_k$. Call this limit $x_{k}^*$. Now you have a vector $x^*$, which is a member of $X$. We claim that there are infinitely many elements of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, in any open sphere around $x^* \in X$. Because, otherwise we do not have the convergence for each component. Having this in mind, we want to construct a sub-sequence of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \subset X$, Starting from an open sphere of radius $r$, around $x^*$, find an element $y_1 \in \{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Then reduce the radius at each step $t$ and you would be able to find an element $y_t \in \{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that is a member of the new sphere. Note that if $y_t=x_k$, then $y_{t+1}=x_{k+p}$, where $p$ is a natural number, just because we want to have a sub-sequence.

Comment: do you have any suggestion about how to show compactness? I thought of using the definition that it should be closed and bounded.

Comment: @user123, I added more explanation. Hope it helps